# how to maintain state in URL even refresh

Tags: reactjs, react-router, routes

```
navigate(`/dashboard`, { state: { stringData: "smart warehouse", id: passData } });
```

Iam using this method to pass datas to dashboard(parent route) and dynamically rendering some functions
refreshing with  on the current dashboard its not losing data. but if we navigate to another page( to the child route)
making a refresh the 'state' data is losing and cant make execute function with using the state data
my route looks like

```
<Route path="/dashboard/" some elements...>
   <Route.....elements   />
   <Route.....elements   />
   <Route.....elements   />
</Route>
```

Iam using react-router and react. please suggest me some methods to do tgis functionality

Comment: This is by design. HTML5 Push State is associated with the browser history, so if you move forward into a new page, it is lost. It sounds like you want to store the state a different way. I would suggest it should be appended as a query parameter or similar. What is the data and what is it used for?

Comment: sounds like query parameter works for me. thank you for introduce that term

Comment: Route state is pretty ephemeral, lasting during the route transition and on the receiving component. If you need to persist it then save it to local state on the receiving end, and if you need to persist it through page refreshes use localStorage. The issue OFC then becomes how/when to invalidate the persisted state.